# rvm issue on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rvm

I'm createing an amazon ec2 server for the first time. I installed `rvm` as my ubuntu user in my ubuntu instance and created a deploy user for my rails app. But when I login as deploy user and move to my code folder I end up with below error
`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@myapp: Permission denied`

Googled but couldn't understand. Can someone suggest me the solution for this please.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the user to rvm group.